# Snow Blower Break In Smell

Tags: troubleshooting, smell, small-engine, break-in

I just started my new snowblower today to try to break it in.  Within maybe a minute it started emitting a "burning metal" smell.  I stopped it and there was some smoke coming out of the air filter.

My initial thought was perhaps low oil but I didn't have any handy.  I'll definitely be picking some up later, however, I was hoping this might just be a normal smell of a new engine being broken in.

I couldn't find anything in the literature or while browsing online.

This is the model:

Ariens Compact ST24LE Two‑Stage Snow Blower, 24"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smell and smoke will just be oil from the manufacturing process burning off the hot parts.  Have you read the manual, it should show you how to check the oil level without having to buy more.  I am presuming here that it is a four stroke engine with oil in the sump.  Can you verify that it is not a two stroke engine that you have to add oil to the fuel?

Update-
Looks like it is 4 stroke, so you won't need oil in the fuel.

Comment: Yes.  I read through the manual and checked the oil.  It definitely has some, but I typically have a very difficult time accurately reading the oil level with fresh oil since it's so translucent on the dip stick.

Comment: Don't add oil unless you can see the level, since adding too much can also cause damage.